# what is the best size of images if I show it in single page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am new and just want to know about the best size of any image if I placed multiple images on a single page and use scroll. I already done with image of size 800*1024 but when I use scrolling, it wont scroll smoothly. Plz help

Comment: The design usability of your app depends on what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: if you use vector drawable images , i guess that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as best size of any image, this depends on the design of your app, on the screen of the phone etc.

Probably this resource will help you: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support

Also, make sure:

- you design your layouts to adapt to all screens sizes and densities
- if you use fixed dimensions use them in dp not px
- if you show images in a list always use a recycle view or a list view implemented with
  view holder pattern, in order for the view to work smoothly and avoid out of memory errors